# Ruby Rails Increment value from database on click

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, increment, vote

it's the first time I work with ruby on rails, so don't be too hard with me. :)
I'm currently working a website project that will have several entries, and people will have to vote for entries. I enter entries on a SQL database (with phpMyAdmin). I have set the following rows : id, title, author, date, voteplus and voteminus (the last two are of type smallint). I would like the users to increment voteplus or voteminus by clicking on a link on my website. I display them this way : `<span class="vote">( #{row[5]} / #{row[6]} )</span>`

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just starting the project, it might make sense to use a gem like `make_votable` for this purpose.  You can find other gems at [ruby toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=voting).  If you don't want to use a gem, you would most likely want to use Activerecord for all your sql queries.  If you're migrating from php (which I don't know anything about), you will want to make sure that all the tables are named properly for Activerecord.  So, my suggestion would be to follow the [Hartl tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) to get an idea for the Rails way of doing things.  If you have a legacy database, I would migrate it up to what you need for Rails (and obviously make a backup)